# Strange Apache Segfault caused by XDebug

Tags: php, apache, segmentation-fault, xdebug

I've got a quite large codebase (nothing too massive though) that is encountering a segfault on the one of the most innocuous lines of code ever.

Basically this (within a class method):

> $this->saved = $saved;

gettype() confirms $saved is a boolean, and it's defined in the class as protected. If I comment it out it runs fine.

Since I disabled XDebug it's started to work, but I can't really get any work done without XDebug.  Any ideas on what it could be and how I can fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If it's caused by XDebug, then you should probably report it at [XDebug's issue tracker](http://bugs.xdebug.org/my_view_page.php).

More importantly though, if you haven't already, upgrade to the latest XDebug and PHP. I mean, perhaps this is fixed already, and you're simply using an old version.